# How to select nested elements by variables? Js

Tags: javascript, select, nested, element

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("lamp");
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

a[0].b[1].style.color = "white";

Why this code is wrong??

Comment: How is "b" part of "a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both a and b are nodelists. A language doesnt work how you think it should.

You need to filter the Class Collection by their tagName, than loop trough and add the style ;)

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("lamp").filter(e=>e.tagName=="div").forEach(e=>e.style.color="white";);
```

However, jquery (a library)  is quite useful in such a case:

```
$("div .lamp").each(function(){
  this.css("color","white");
});
```